AWS policies are being weird
{
   Effect = "Allow",
   Action = [
      "s3:*",
   ],
   Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::lab-etl-s3",
}

I am creating a S3 bucket and a login user with terraform and aws. And I am attaching this particular policy to the user. But I cannot see the created S3 in the list. It says
You don't have permissions to list buckets
I am now sure what I am doing wrong
I am creating a clould lab kind of project. Where people can provision some resource in my aws account. They only have access to the particular resource. They cannot see any other user's resources. But I cant able to do this in the way

That policy allows you to make any S3 API request against the lab-etl-s3 bucket. It doesn't allow you to list all buckets in the account, however. The error message explains how to give that permission (assuming that is actually what you want to do). Note that you're not going to be able to use the S3 console to list only those buckets that you have access to, however.

Also note that arn:aws:s3:::lab-etl-s3 only relates to the bucket itself. It doesn't give you any permissions on the objects in the bucket, which would be arn:aws:s3:::lab-etl-s3/*.

Here is one way to share a single S3 bucket between multiple IAM users, each with their own folder and own set of permissions.

How these platforms like cloud academy are achieving this?

"How these platforms like cloud academy are achieving this?" How are they achieving what exactly?

You can go to thier platform and start a lab. It will give you a temp creadentials. When logging in that. You will only be able to access or list the resources that are particular for you. How are they acheiving this if the ListAllBucket is either ListAll or ListNone kind of principle?

A common solution that cloud lab-like vendors use is to have a pool of AWS accounts, each of which has suitably low quotas, and they nuke and recycle the accounts when you are done.
